# Connecting SQL Server to online?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a SQL server (Express Edition) which is working internally within the LAN network, now my task is to make this query process to be done from anywhere (Instead of LAN) because some of the employees will be on tour so I need to let it available to everyone so that those who are using the VB.Net form they will get connected with the SQL server.

[Microsoft Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483(v=sql.105).aspx)

I read the info from the above link but I don't know where to enter the IP address and all.

I already requested the tech team to offer a static IP address and they also confirmed that they will be giving a static IP for SQL server.  But where to enter that static IP and all is a mysterious things for me.

Anyone please add your valuable suggestion about how to make this SQL server available for online so that our company employees can access it with the help of VB.Net form.

Awaiting for your suggestions.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site about programming. Exposing the database to the Internet though is *not* a programming question and has **very serious** security implications. You need to learn about firewalls, proxies, VPNs *and* implement them correctly. Just getting an internal static IP isn't enough, that IP should either be a public one, or your firewall/proxies should be configured to forward requests to the server. The technical team should understand that.

Comment: Instead of trying to set a VPN and/or proxies from scratch, why don't you move to SQL Azure? Setting up and securing is done OOTB. Much, much cheaper and safer than a data breach, or hiring an external consultant that knows how to configure and secure database accessa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions, finally I found a step by step Video Tutorial which helped me to connect my SQL server over online

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOUDdUJ5BLY